# Progress bar with specific path with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

is there a way to achieve this? 
What I would really like to do is to change gradually color of a line following the value of a jquery UI slider, but following a specific path, so I could achieve something like this:

[image]

I can't come up with a good way to achieve this, any suggestions?
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: What @JayBlanchard said :) First thought is something involving background images. One red layer (solid background), then a div with a blue background (z-indexed below the main content. Then the actual lines are transparent parts of PNGs. As you slide the bar, observe its position in Javascript and move the blue div first to the right (between two slider values) and then downwards (between two later slide values) and then left (another range on the slider). It's not too elegant, but it might just work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that is exactly what I did in the first place. But a problem I had was that if I moved the slider quickly, the divs would start moving all at the same time. Anyway, what I found to be more accurate is to use three progress bar following the path of the lines

Answer (score 0):

I've only used jquery ui progress bar once before but based on the examples and things that I have seen when trying to implement it the first time I don't think so. I best I have seen is making the bar realizable.